# TypeError in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

My problem is that I want to show the content of a `.txt` file in the browser using JavaScript (specifically Node.js), but when I try to run the code, it shows `TypeError: Header name must be a valid HTTP Token ["Content-Type "]`. The code is following (I have seen this code in a tutorial):

```js
var http=require('http');
var fs=require('fs');

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    console.log("Request was made" + req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type ': 'text/plain'});
    var myReadStream=fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/readMe.txt', 'utf8');
    myReadStream.pipe(res);

    });
    server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Listening to port 3000');
```

And specifically, it points out the mistake is in this part of the code:

```js
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type ': 'text/plain'});
```

I would like to know what is the problem.

Comment: Space after "Content-Type"?

Comment: Hi...? How is my answer going?

Answer (score 2):

You have an space here:
[image]

Just remove the space: `'Content-Type':` instead of `'Content-Type ':`

Answer (score 0):

**Issue for blank space in here** [![enter image description here][1]][1]

using for this code:-

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.creteServer(function(req,res)
{

```
console.log("Request was made" + req.url);
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/readMe.txt', 'utf8');
myReadStream.pipe(res);
```

});

server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Listening to port 3000');